# Jquery Mobile: loading spinner going crazy on second start-up

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

In my (android) phonegap app, I've added the code below to show a loading-spinner while logging in on facebook.
At first start-up, it works beautifuly. However, when I press the back-button and launch the app again, the spinner is out of control: it spins way too fast and with short pauzes. Also, the spinner appears not in the center of the screen, but slightly higher (it looks like it's centered with my text that follows afterwards).

Anyone familiar with this issue and knows how to fix it?

```
function DeviceReadyListener() {
    $.mobile.loading( 'show' );
    console.log("Device ready");
    try {
        FB.init({ appId:"xxx", nativeInterface:CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs:false });
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        getLoginStatus();
        document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah..I had the same issue some months ago..I couldn't solve it so I used spin.js...another option would be to take off the loading gif and just show text..

Comment: Guess I'll just use the text for now... thanks!